# Ionic 4 version rollback

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8

Hi I want to rollback in a version of ionic [where the format was like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnEMb.png) and [not like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1H4v9.png) Anyone have the idea what version is this? Reason for rolling back: I dont want to get confused in the tutorials

Comment: Since they are text, please include the content of your links in your post instead of redirecting users elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic v4,  Ionic removed their homegrown router and replaced it with the router of the framework.   This allowed them to open the door for React and VUE to be the underlying framework instead of just Angular.

What you're seeing is the Angular Router.  There is 5x more documentation on Angular Router out there, so if you're worried about tutorials?  You will simply need to google Angular Router 7/8.

Comment: Yes. The angular router is good. But I'm currently watching a series of tutorial whereas the teacher is using the much previous angular routing format. I want a peace of mind that there's nothing wrong in the routing part.